# Implementing hash table, insert function resulting in "scope" errors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hash

I probably should do more research before I ask this but I am getting too frustrated for searching on-line.

Im doing a school assignment and it involves implementing a hash table, so i tried to initialize the bucket with chaining like this

inside Hashtable.h

```
private:

Node **buckets; //trying to create an array of pointers
```

inside Hashtable.cpp

```
Hashtable::Hashtable()
{
buckets=new Node*[1000];
}

void insert(char * value,int r, string previous)
{
int find=hashfcn(value);
Node *x =buckets[find];
}
```

Im using code blocks right now and the error I am getting is for the line in insert

> error: 'buckets' was not declared in this scope|

I have no idea why its not, can someone help me out, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `Hashtable::`. It should be:

```
void Hashtable::insert(char * value,int r, string previous)
{
int find=hashfcn(value);
Node *x =buckets[find];
}
```

I'm sure you already know this, but as it is now, you're just defining a free function, and it has no idea what `buckets` is. You need to specify that you're defining a member function of `Hashtable` with `Hashtable::` before the function name, then it can see that by `buckets` you mean the member variable of the invoking `Hashtable` named `buckets`.